# Generate payment from more than 1 columns in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I would like to generate the total payment in every customer order in MYSQL.
Every Order has order detail(s). Table sample would be like this.
Table Order:

```
ID        Customer Name      
-------   -------            
001       Jane
```

Table Order Detail :

```
Order ID  Product      Product Amount     Price (per product)
-------   -------      -------            -----
001       Pen          1                  $20
001       Book         2                  $5
```

So, the output should be like this:

```
Order ID  Customer Name      Total    
-------   -------            -------
001       Jane               $30
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`.

Comment: there are too many tags for no code; have you tried anything at all before posting?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query :

```
select
    OrderId,
    CustomerName,
    sum(ProductAmount*Price) as Total
from
    Order O
    inner join OrderDetail OD on
        O.Id = OD.Id
group by
    OrderID,
    CustomerName
```